# static object initialisation

Tags: java

Everytime FutureContent.future is called why will a new MyFuture class not be created and assigned to future ?

```
FutureContent.future

public class FutureContent {

        public static MyFuture future = new MyFuture();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "call" `FutureContent.future`, you reference it.

It's initialized once, at class load time; there's no need to initialize it again. That's what the `static` part means (broadly).

Answer (score 1):

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.

[Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

Precisely because `future` is a static field -- aka, a class variable -- which means the initialisation will only happen once.

Comment: I'd rather say, "precisely because `future` is a *field*"

Comment: @Kirk: Perhaps a combination of the two: "precisely because `future` is a static field".

Comment: @LukeH No, not really. Making the example's field non-static does not change the fact that accessing the field does not trigger creating new MyFutures like the OP think it does. It only changes that it is now created once per object creation rather than once per class load.